# How to write bitmap into file asynchronously?

Tags: android, bitmap, rx-java, rx-android

I have a cameraX application, where user can take a photo and then full-size photo appears on the screen with "Save" and "Cancel" buttons.
When the user taps "Save" I need to write this image(bitmap) to external dir., and immediately close this full-screen image and go to the camera screen again. But I have some delay before image screen disappears.
I'm using FileOutputStream to save bitmap into my external directory, with a bitmap.compress() method, but it seems that all this is done synchronously, in UI thread.

I'm trying to learn RxJava and don't know, is it possible to do this asynchronously with Rx?

Comment: I think you can use a Worker for the actual saving of the image. You could also do this fairly easily using Coroutines in Kotlin.

Comment: Yes, know about coroutines, but i'm trying to learn Rx, and want to know is it possible to do this? Or RxJava not used for such tasks ?

Comment: Put the used code in a thread.

Comment: @Rarity7- Of Course, you can use Rx for asynchronous tasks as well. You can achieve what you want with `Observable.fromCallable.....`